# Why my specified controller changes to Home controller on using @Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am using below source code to use the image as a navigation link for the specified Product/Productlistview (controller/action).

**CODE:**

```
@Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("Milk Products", "Productlistview", "Product", new { categoryid = 1 }).ToHtmlString().Replace("Milk Products", "<img src=\"/Content/ImagesDairy/Milk-products.jpg\" />"))
```

But on execution, the code the navigation path changes to Home/productListView. Why and how I can maintain my specified path?

Comment: What is your expected url  ? check my answer this is seems you are want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Productlistview", "Product", new { categoryid = 1 })">
    <img src="/Content/ImagesDairy/Milk-products.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: @sksaini mark as answer as well so other can have better idea